# Does there exist a continuous function $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \circ f(x) = -x$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exist a continuous function $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f \circ f(x) = -x$ for all $x$?

My feeling is that there isn't, but I don't know how to go about proving this.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is bijective, as $f^{-1} = -f$, and is continuous, $f$ needs to be increasing or decreasing. But the composition of increasing functions is increasing. And composition of decreasing functions is increasing.